# React Redux, Update part of state with immutability-helper update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability, reducers

in my redux reducer state, I want to update an attribute inside an object of objects.

```
    {
    users:{
        '1':{id:'1', name:'', items:[], ....}
        '2':{id:'1', name:'', items:[], ....}
         ...
         }
    }
```

I want to update just for instance `items` in object with key `1 or 2` or any other key and rest of state untouched. the action contains the key number as `action.id`, and `action.payload` contains the String.

I got confused how the `spread` and `update` works and how to keep the rest of `users` objects untouched.

of course my code is wrong :) but I tried

```
case types.UPDATE_ITEMS: {
      return update(...state, {
        [action.id]: { items: { $set: action.payload } }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly the usage of the `update`, it will keep the rest of the state untouched. so there was no need for spread

```
   case types.UPDATE_ITEMS:
          return update(state, {
            [action.id]: {
              items: { $set: action.payload }
            }
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update just the `users` part using the rest spread operator like this:

```
case types.UPDATE_ITEMS:
  return {
    ...state, // That will keep any other keys in the object besides 'users'
    users: {
      ...state.users, // keep the part you want to keep from 'users',
      [action.id]: {
        ...state.users[action.id], // keep the part you want from this user
        items: [action.payload] // update the part you want
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi Amir, using the `rest spread` operator you don't need the `immutability helper`.

Comment: here on the users:{   I get  Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: are you sure there is a `1` key in the `users` object inside the state already?

Comment: can you print out your state object here before returning this update?

Comment: what I have written in the post is what I see in the store state and users is the only object now is the state, with keyed objects inside.( just added a pair of { })

Comment: based on what you have mentioned, looks like `state.users` is undefined by the time you pass it inside the reducer.